# Store and retrive data from 2 html files in chrome websql using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, web-sql

I have a HTML file in which there are two text box's named username and password.The username and passwords are stored in the table name "Login".

I have another HTML which has first name,lastname,age and email.I want to store this first name,lastname,age and email in the same  table "Login".

I tried doing this but cannot see the columns for first name,lastname,age and email in the table login.

- 1st HTML file:

  ```
  var db=window.openDatabase('LOGINFORM','1.0','LOGINFORM',200000);

  var createStatement = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS login (username TEXT, password TEXT,fame TEXT,lname TEXT,age INT,email TEXT)";

  var insertStatement = 'INSERT INTO login (username, password) VALUES (?, ?)';
  ```
- 2nd HTML file:

  ```
  var insertStatement = " INSERT INTO login(firstname,lastname,age,email) VALUES (?, ? , ?, ? )";

  var updateStatement = "UPDATE login SET firstname = ?, lastname = ? ,age=?,email=? ";
  ```

Answer (score -1):

First you have to add fields in login table... first name,last name, age and email.

Now the table has username, password, first name,last name,age and email.

Then you can you for authentication, inserting, and updating records. depends up to you..

Comment: You can see the above code that I have did that and still cannot able to see the fields in the table.